# Copying each row of matrix to a temporary array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I want to copy a row (one each team iterating) of a 500x8 `matrix` to a temp array with the name `actual_row`. This is what I've tried.

```
int matrix[500][8]; // this has been already filled by int's
int actual_row[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
         actual_row[j] = matrix[i][j];
         printf("The row is: ");
         for(int q = 0; q < 8; q++) {
                 printf(" %d ",actual_row[q]);
         // do other stuff
         }
      }
printf("\n");
}
```

This is not printing the line, it's printing 0's and 1's sometime, so there's something I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is slightly off.  You need to copy the row to `actual_row`, then print the contents.  Furthermore, why not just print the contents while you are copying the matrix row to `actual_row`:

```
printf("The row is: ");
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    actual_row[j] = matrix[i][j];         
    printf(" %d ",actual_row[j]);
    // do other stuff
}
```

So your code snippet should be this:

```
int matrix[500][8]; // this has been already filled by int's
int actual_row[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    printf("The row is: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        actual_row[j] = matrix[i][j];         
        printf(" %d ",actual_row[j]);
       // do other stuff
    }
    // <--at this point, actual_row fully contains your row
 printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't print `actual_row` before it's filled completely:

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
     actual_row[j] = matrix[i][j];
 }

 printf("The row is: ");
 for(int q = 0; q < 8; q++) {
      printf(" %d ",actual_row[q]);
      ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is slightly off (no need for the third nested loop).  You need to copy the row to `actual_row` (which you did), and print the contents within the same loop:

```
 printf("The row is: ");
 for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
     actual_row[j] = matrix[i][j];         
     printf(" %d ",actual_row[j]);
     // do other stuff
 }
```